# spring and different way to avoid to use new

Tags: spring, design-patterns

I use spring boot 2.

I need to validate many condition, instead of creating many if, I create a class for every condition who implements isValid method.

```
public interface Rulecondition<T>{
  boolean isValid(){
}

public class ClientGroup implements Rulecondition<Billing>{
  private Billing billing;

  public ClientGroup(Billing billing){
    this.billing=billing;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(){
    return true; //only for example...
  }

}
```

I create a class who use a stream of all condition and verify if everything is valid

```
@Component
public class ConditionRuleEngine{
  private List<Rulecondition> rules = new ArrayList<>();

  public ConditionRuleEngine(){

  }


  public void addRule(Rulecondition rule){
    rules.add(rule);
  }

  public boolean conditionApply(){
    retunr rules.stream().allMatch(r->.isValid()));
  }

}
```

In a service class, I autowired ConditionRuleEngine

```
@Service
public class OperationService(){

  private final ConditionRuleEngine conditionRuleEngine;

  @Autowired
  public OperationService OperationService(final ConditionRuleEngine conditionRuleEngine){
    this.conditionRuleEngine=conditionRuleEngine;
  }

  public void execute(Billing billing){

      //need to add condition

      conditionRuleEngine.run(); 
  }

}
```

Is there any better way to add condition then creating a new?

```
ClientGroup cg = new ClientGroup(billing);
conditionRuleEngine.add(cg);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spring so I'll not dare to answer your very question. However if your use case is about validating objects, why not use Bean Validation instead? (https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but there is one change that would help your situation: Removing the generic type argument, `T`, from the `Rulecondition` interface. Since `Rulecondition` only contains a `isValid` method that does not depend on the generic parameter, `T`, that parameter can be safely removed:

```
public interface RuleCondition {
    boolean isValid();
}
```

The reason for this removal is that it simplifies the Spring-based solution to your problem. Without that generic parameter, you can now mark each of your `RuleCondition` implementations with `@Component` (making them eligible for dependency injection) and autowire a `List<RuleCondition>` into your `ConditionRuleEngine` class:

```
@Component
public class ConditionRuleEngine {

    @Autowired
    private List<RuleCondition> rules;

    // ...other implementation details...
}
```

Spring will inject all of the components that implement `RuleCondition` into the `rules` field.

---

While removing the generic parameter, `T`, simplifies the solution, it is not required.

If you do need to maintain the generic parameter, `T`, then you can autowire the `RuleCondition` for each generic parameter by specifying the parameter in the `List` type:

```
public interface RuleCondition<T> {
    boolean isValid(T value);
}

@Component
public class ClientGroup implements RuleCondition<Billing> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Billing value) {
        // ...
    }
}

@Component
public class ConditionRuleEngine {

    @Autowired
    private List<RuleCondition<Billing>> billingRules;

    @Autowired
    private List<RulecCndition<Other>> otherRules;

    // ...other implementation details...
}
```

Spring will inject all `RuleCondition` objects that match the generic parameter. For example, `billingRules` will contain a `List` of all `RuleCondition<Billing>` (and will *not* include any `RulecCndition<Other>` objects.

Comment: ok but i will need to use a new for the rule to feed the list

Comment: @roberttrudel There is no need to `new` in this case. By denoting each rule with `@Component`, Spring will automatically inject the rule in the appropriate `List` object. Where is your concern with using `new`?

Comment: rule need data that change, that why i passed value to the constructor ClientGroup cg = new ClientGroup(billing);

Comment: @roberttrudel Understood. Sorry, I made a typo: I thought the `isValid` method in `RuleConidition<T>` already contained an argument of type `T`. I've updated the example to now include that argument. Does that resolve the issue? If you still need a `Billing` object in the constructor, you can `@Autowired` it into the constructor.

Comment: how do you add rule to the list?

Comment: @roberttrudel You create a new class that implements `RuleCondition<T>`, where `T` is the object that the rule will handle (such as `Billing`) and annotate the new class with `@Component`. Spring will then populate the `List<RuleCondition<T>>` objects (like `List<RuleCondition<Billing>>`) with all an object of the classes annotated with `@Component`. For example, since `ClientGroup` is annotated with `@Component`, `billingRules` will contain a `ClientGroup` object.

Comment: not realy sure if if i have different rule with same T. Also because parameter change at runtime, not sure that can with only with component annotation on class who implements RuleCondition